# Cin input being skipped in do/while loop

Tags: c++, while-loop, switch-statement, cin

```
cin >> subchoice;
        switch(subchoice)
        {
        case 1:
            gold = gold - 5;
            cout << "Now you only have " << gold << " gold.\n";
            cout << "blah blah";
            health = 100;
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "blah blah"
                    << "1 - Head Back in and Buy a Bed\n"
                    << "2 - Find a Clothier Shop\n"
                    << "3 - Find a Blacksmith's\n";
            cin >> subsubchoice;
            switch(subsubchoice)
            {
            case 1:
                gold = gold - 5;
                cout << "Now you only have " << gold << " gold.\n";
                cout << "blah blah"
                health = 100;
                break;
            case 2:
                menuchoice = subsubchoice;
                break;
            case 3:
                menuchoice = subsubchoice;
                break;
            }
        }

    break;
    case 2:

    }




} while (!boolchoice);
```

Hey so I have this piece of code here. And whenever I run it, it always skips the cin input for subsubchoice. What it is supposed to do is take that input and either make you go into the inn or make apply that choice to menuchoice and restart you back at the beginning of the do-while loop. I have no idea why it is skipping the input and then closing out of the program. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to add `cin.ignore()` before `cin >> subsubchoice;`

Answer (score 0):

Could you explain the format of your input? cin reads all input until a whitespace character ('\n', '\t', ' ' etc.) is found. Is there any possibility you insert a whitespace in your original input, such as "2 1"?

Comment: when I am typing in the input I just press the corresponding button then press enter so I would press [1] [ENTER] then some text would display for a split second, I could make out saying the text in the first case 2 but then it closes out. I just tried the cin.ignore(); and that didn't make a difference.

Comment: What is the type of the variable subsubchoice?

Comment: right now they are short int, but I tried int and it didn't change

Comment: could you copy-paste from the terminal? What is more, I still wonder what the initial value of boolchoice is. :D

Comment: well I set boolchoice in the beginning where it says "Press 1 To Start" which then leads into the do/while so that I can return to it later in the program. Also, the terminal closes as soon as I put the input for subchoice. http://imgur.com/cLVSY8N As soon as I press 2 and enter it flashes the text that case 2 has in cout very quickly then closes.

Comment: This seems peculiar. Try using:
cin.get(subsubchoice);
cin.ignore();

Comment: also add a cin.ignore() at the end of your code to keep the terminal open, as I see you use Windows.

Comment: I just tried that both before and after the code and one before/one after and those didn't work. http://justpaste.it/ctext here is the full code.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

1. There is a missing semi-colon in cout << "You quickly head back into the warm inn and relax into a warm night and sleep well. Your health is restored to 100.\n";
2. remove the last case 2: or add a break; after it (better remove it, it is useless).
3. while (!boolchoice) is guaranteed to be false, because in order to enter the forst if, boolchoice has to be non-zero. if you want it to iterate, try using while (gold) or while (health) to exit when you are either out of gold or health...

I hope this helps...